# Save a Jtable to a file I created with a boolean column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, boolean, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to save a jtable on exit but I can't because I have a boolean as one of my columns. Can anyone explain to me how to get rid of `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String`?

this is my code to save on Exit.

```
private void btnBckMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
         BufferedWriter bfw = null;
        try {
            bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
            for(int i = 0 ; i < tabTask.getColumnCount() ; i++)
            {
                bfw.write(tabTask.getColumnName(i));
                bfw.write("\t");
            }         for (int i = 0 ; i < tabTask.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                bfw.newLine();
                for(int j = 0 ; j < tabTask.getColumnCount();j++)
                {
                    bfw.write((String)(tabTask.getValueAt(i,j)));
      bfw.write("\t");
    }
  }         bfw.close();
            fireBackEvent();
        } catch (IOException ex) {               
            Logger.getLogger(SubList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bfw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SubList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the line `bfw.write((String)(tabTask.getValueAt(i,j)));` is not correct. If you have boolean column you can't cast it to string.

Use e.g. bfw.write(""+tabTask.getValueAt(i,j));

Or check class and cast the value depending on the class. Like this

```
Object value=tabTask.getValueAt(i,j);
if (value!=null) {
  if (value instanceof String) {
    bfw.write((String)value);
  }
  else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
    bfw.write(Boolean.toString(value));
  }
}
```